# Is the Treblinka Archaeology study a hoax?

Tags: history, archaeology, holocaust

[Treblinka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treblinka_extermination_camp) was a Nazi extermination site for Polish Jews between July 1942 and October 1943. Jews [were claimed](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/03/31/nazi-death-camp-treblinka-excavated-archaeologists_n_5062114.html?ir=India&adsSiteOverride=in) to have been shipped to Treblinka and upon arrival immediately executed by carbon monoxide gas. All together, upwards of 900,000 Jews were [claimed](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-16657363) to be murdered there.

[Caroline Sturdy Colls](http://www.staffs.ac.uk/staff/profiles/cs30.jsp), an expert in [Holocaust Archaeology](http://www.maneyonline.com/doi/full/10.1179/1574077312Z.0000000005), reports in her 2015 paper *[Forensic and Archaeological Approaches to Sites of the Holocaust](http://eprints.staffs.ac.uk/2160/1/Killing%20Sites%20Paper%20CSC%20Final.pdf)* that:

> At Treblinka, the graves were able to provide some information about the individuals interred within them, even though the excavations were only confirmatory. Shoes which show evidence of multiple hand completed repairs and severe wear tell us something of the life of the owner. Bullets intermingled with the remains reveal the fate of many but also act as evidence concerning how ammunition travelled during the war. Other items, such as these found in the area around the gas chambers, which were also surveyed and partially excavated, reveal both personal stories
>   relating to both pre-war and war time life, and the collective experiences of the many women sent to their deaths.

However, [Holocaust revisionist](http://germarrudolf.com/germars-views/false-claims-about-revisionism/) [Eric Hunt](http://holocausthandbooks.com/index.php?author_id=15) had previously released a Treblinka holocaust denial documentary called *[The Treblinka Archaeology Hoax](https://archive.org/details/TheTreblinkaArchaeologyHoax)* questioning the findings at Treblinka such as digging near clearly marked Christian graves claiming to find new "hidden mass graves", falsely assigning homicidal intent to a normal life-saving shower room at Majdanek, and [misidentifying a terra-cotta tile](http://newobserveronline.com/smithsonian-red-faced-after-treblinka-star-of-david-tiles-shown-to-be-not-jewish-at-all/) excavated at Treblinka as a Star of David tile belonging to the floor of a homicidal "gas chamber".

So is 'The Holocaust Landscapes Project Study for Treblinka Extermination and Labour Camps, Poland' by Caroline Sturdy Colls a hoax as noted [here](http://www.westernspring.co.uk/treblinka-forensic-examination-fails/), [here](https://archive.org/details/TreblinkaInvestigation-GroundPenetratingRadarStudy), [here](http://www.theforbiddentruth.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1073) and [here](http://www.godlikeproductions.com/forum1/message2585181/pg1?disclaimer=1) by [conspiracy theorists](http://content.time.com/time/specials/packages/article/0,28804,1860871_1860876_1861026,00.html)?

Comment: The trouble with asking if something was a hoax, is that it implies that it was deliberate - i.e. motivation, which is hard or impossible to prove. Is it enough to ask if it reached the wrong conclusions?

Comment: This is way too broad, what claim are you specifically skeptical of?

Comment: @Skliwz-The main claims of Eric Hunt that should be viewed skeptically are digging near marked graves to find new "hidden mass graves", Treblinka “steam rooms”, LIDAR ground penetrating radar proving that there were massive pits which at one time held the remains of 900,000 Jews and misidentified terracota tile etc from various other claims mentioned here-http://www.dailystormer.com/questions-for-top-holohoaxer-dr-caroline-sturdy-colls/

Comment: @Oddthinking- There are more animal bones here than alleged human bones Colls found in the entirety of Treblinka 2 and per Caroline Colls’ Ground Penetrating Radar there simply are no markings signifying massive mass graves which could possibly have held 900,000 bodies referring to the denier's claims for the Treblinka archaeology findings to be a hoax in this document-http://www.adelaideinstitute.org/newsletters/Newsletter%20841.pdf

Comment: ... Sorry, did you just refer to an article from an active and outspoken neo-nazi website to back up a claim about holocaust denial?